# Set of flat curves with filling in 3D plot

Tags: plotting

I'm trying to draw 3D plot from my experimental points in the way shown at the figure below:

[image]

I tried to use ListPointPlot3D for that, but obviously there is no option Joined as in ListPlot.

```
mydata = Table[{x, y, x*y*y}, {x, 0, 1, 0.03}, {y, 0, 10, 1}];
ListPointPlot3D[mydata, Filling -> Bottom, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, RGBColor[y, 0., 0.3]]]
```

So I obtained this:

[image]

Any idea how I can join the point to obtain the set of flat curves with filling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see an easy way to do this with `ListPointPlot3D` or by layering a bunch of 2D `ListPlot`s in a 3D box. However, it's fairly straightforward to do this manually, with basic graphics primitives. The shape of each curve is simply a polygon that traverses all the points in each row, but also includes one point at at `z = 0` below the first and last point in the list. You'll just have to take care of colouring yourself:

```
color[n_] := With[{palette = ColorData[97, "ColorList"]},
  palette[[Mod[n, Length@palette, 1]]]
]
Graphics3D[
  MapIndexed[
    {
      Opacity@0.5,
      color@#2[[1]],
      Polygon[Join[#, {Last@#*{1, 1, 0}, First@#*{1, 1, 0}}]]
    } &,
    mydata
  ],
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1/2},
  Axes -> True,
  Lighting -> "Neutral"
]
```

[image]

Note that this fills in the `y-z` planes. If you want to fill in the `x-z` planes instead, simply use `Transpose @ mydata` inside the `MapIndexed` instead:

[image]