# How to create several 3D plots of 2D functions in Mathematica?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I have multiple 2D functions defined and I'd like to plot them in (what I call) a fence plot. An example of a fence plot is [image: Fence Plot]

The three functions I want to plot (all defined on $-1 <= x <= 1$) are:

- $f(x) = 0.5x + 0.5$
- $g(x) = -0.5x + 0.5$, and
- $h(x) = 0.5$

Can someone show me how to do this in Mathematica?

Comment: Why not use `ParametricPlot3D[]`?

Comment: f[x_] := 0.5 x + 0.5; g[x_] := \[Minus]0.5 x + 0.5; h[x_] := 0.5; Plot[{f[x], g[x], h[x]}, {x, -1, 1}], you looking for? Or Plot3D[{f[x], g[x], h[x]}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]

Comment: [Duplicate?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/40585/2305) Much like [this earlier question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/111522/2305) which is only a discretisation away from yours.

Comment: @J.M. I looked at that, but wasn't sure if it applied here. (I'm a Mathematica plotting novice.)

Comment: @Louis I was hoping for something more like the `Plot3D`, but that doesn't do what I need. In fact, it fails.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So the idea here is to generate a plot, use the `Filling->Axis` option, then extract the polygons from that.

```
Options[fencePlot] = {"YValues" -> Automatic, "Colors" -> Automatic};
fencePlot[funcs_, {x_, xmin_, xmax_},  
    opts : OptionsPattern[{fencePlot, Graphics3D}]] :=
 Module[{yv, pgons, colors},
    yv = OptionValue["YValues"] /. Automatic -> Range[Length[funcs]];
  colors = (OptionValue["Colors"] /. Automatic -> (ColorData[97])) /@ 
    Range[Length[funcs]];
  pgons = Table[{colors[[n]],
          Cases[

       Plot[funcs[[n]], {x, xmin, xmax}, Filling -> Axis, 
         PlotRange -> All] // Normal, 
              Polygon[__], Infinity] /. 
            Polygon[a__] :> Polygon[{#1, yv[[n]], #2} & @@@ a]}
        , {n, Length@yv}];
    Graphics3D[
      pgons
     , Evaluate@FilterRules[{opts}, Options[Graphics3D]] ,
    Axes -> True]
    ]
```

Called via

```
fencePlot[{-.5 x + .5, .5 x + .5, .5}, {x, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

Or

```
fencePlot[Sin[π # x] & /@ Range[6, 0, -1], {x, 0, 1}, 
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I'm thinking of. Can you change the color of each plot?

Comment: Working on that now

Comment: Would've used the indexed colors myself, tho.

Comment: I was looking at those but I don't fully understand them.  Do they only take integer inputs? Do they all take the same range?  They don't go from 0 to 1, so I'm at a loss

Comment: This is great. I don't understand all of it, but it does what I need it to do. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: @J.M. - I modified it to use an indexed color function, but I can't seem to get it to work with both of these at the same time:  `"Colors" -> ColorData[97]` and `"Colors"->"Colors" -> ({EdgeForm[{Blue, Thick}], 
    FaceForm[{Opacity[0], White}]} &)`  I want it to be more versatile.

Answer (score 4):

Using `ParametricPlot3D` as suggested by @J.M. in the OP comments.

With functions

```
f[x_] := 0.5 x + 0.5
g[x_] := -0.5 x + 0.5
h[x_] := 0.5
```

Then

```
ParametricPlot3D[
 Evaluate[MapIndexed[{First@#2, u, v #1[u]} &]@{f, g, h}], 
  {u, -1, 1}, {v, 0, 1}, 
 PlotRange -> Full,
 PlotStyle -> Opacity[.85],
 Mesh -> None]
```

[image]

`ParametricPlot3D` has attribute hold all so `Evaluate` needs to be called on `MapIndexed` for there to be three functions (each with its own colour) instead of one function (all three would have same colour).  See `PlotStlye` for info on how to customise colours for the functions.

Hope this helps.