# How to plot 3D graphic from sets of inequalities with one discrete axis?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I have 4 sets of inequalities defining a closed region in 2D.

```
eq = {-2.2935076096752747` - Subscript[K, d] + 
  6.808229911479505` Subscript[K, i] < 
 0 && -5.763766885115767` - Subscript[K, d] + 
  0.009355320091888606` Subscript[K, i] < 
 0 && -11.502684761149357` - Subscript[K, d] + 
  0.001987089809253273` Subscript[K, i] < 0 && 
3.46340304560584` - Subscript[K, d] + 
  0.04542417164482498` Subscript[K, i] > 0 && 
8.537116309367326` - Subscript[K, d] + 
  0.0037660209728445602` Subscript[K, i] > 0 && 
14.534182608551115` - Subscript[K, d] + 
  0.001221044796678191` Subscript[K, i] > 0 && 
Kp == 0.5, -1.604921075546996` - Subscript[K, d] + 
  0.6925589409886266` Subscript[K, i] < 
 0 && -5.786642271389586` - Subscript[K, d] + 
  0.009244731146798546` Subscript[K, i] < 
 0 && -11.509573547679` - Subscript[K, d] + 
  0.0019844016231937473` Subscript[K, i] < 0 && 
3.3439113785107626` - Subscript[K, d] + 
  0.05008377356287994` Subscript[K, i] > 0 && 
8.522465980907986` - Subscript[K, d] + 
  0.003778957659603982` Subscript[K, i] > 0 && 
14.529247935512808` - Subscript[K, d] + 
  0.0012218569337417472` Subscript[K, i] > 0 && 
Kp == 2.5, -0.8211478234907658` - Subscript[K, d] + 
  0.3265086224409325` Subscript[K, i] < 
 0 && -5.802882397109164` - Subscript[K, d] + 
  0.009138121629927757` Subscript[K, i] < 
 0 && -11.515757528942748` - Subscript[K, d] + 
  0.0019817256743999857` Subscript[K, i] < 0 && 
3.124003074539731` - Subscript[K, d] + 
  0.05675256117367748` Subscript[K, i] > 0 && 
8.50593069778869` - Subscript[K, d] + 
  0.0037920495232265415` Subscript[K, i] > 0 && 
14.523969834762996` - Subscript[K, d] + 
  0.0012226709659726972` Subscript[K, i] > 0 && Kp == 5, 
0.16873913996616716` - Subscript[K, d] + 
  0.1853676602926451` Subscript[K, i] < 
 0 && -5.812793495347904` - Subscript[K, d] + 
  0.009035141486771207` Subscript[K, i] < 
 0 && -11.521241128822854` - Subscript[K, d] + 
  0.0019790617042690774` Subscript[K, i] < 0 && 
2.6930975155249706` - Subscript[K, d] + 
  0.06857354659267068` Subscript[K, i] > 0 && 
8.487476503798769` - Subscript[K, d] + 
  0.00380530283044807` Subscript[K, i] > 0 && 
14.518347131293424` - Subscript[K, d] + 
  0.0012234869204936912` Subscript[K, i] > 0 && Kp == 7.5};
```

My intention is to find valid PID controller coefficients. First I had the range of Kp from 0.5 to 7.5 and I divided the interval into 4 and find sets of inequalities for corresponding Kp values.

Now I want to plot those 4 planes along the vertical[Kp] axis. But couldn't do it.

I have tried ParametricPlot3D, RegionPlot3d with RegionFunction but none worked. The types of visualizations are not well or seems not work intended.[image: Region Plot]
[image: Parametric Plot]

Comment: What are you looking for? You can change `BoxRatios` maybe?

Comment: I am not sure if ı am using this in a right way or not. If right, how to visualize smooth surfaces. Do you know anyway to plot a region with 3rd axis as discrete value

Comment: And ı dont know how to use multiple region functions for different sets of equations. Or do ı need to plot them separately and show all into one as ı did in regionplot?

Comment: How about [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/111540/how-to-create-several-3d-plots-of-2d-functions-in-mathematica)

Comment: I need to check it. Aswers are seems to be ok for analytical functions. Where ı have inequalities or at least regions defined between different lines. I am on mobile now. Will check soon.